# Is there way to see `man` document only for specified option of a command

Tags: man, options

If I want to know the meaning of `wget -b`, I see the manual by `man wget`, then search the `-b` option.

```
   -b
   --background
       Go to background immediately after startup.  If no output file is specified via the -o, output is redirected to wget-log.
```

I want to get the result by a command like `man wget -b`. (Of course this doesn't work.)

Is there a similar way to make it possible?

Comment: wget -h | grep '\-b'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could redirect the manpage to `awk` and extact the part:

```
man wget | awk '/^ *-b *.*$/,/^$/{print}'
       -b
       --background
           Go to background immediately after startup.  If no output file is specified via the -o, output is redirected to wget-log.
```

That part is everything that is between a `-b` and an empty line.

Comment: `{print}` can be omitted

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use with `GNU Awk 4.0.1(Ubuntu)`, `GNU Awk 3.1.7(CentOS)` and `awk version 20070501(OS X)`, but works only with `4.0.1`.

Comment: `.*$` can be omitted too

Answer (score 23):

If you use `less` as pager for man you can try

```
LESS="+/^\s+-b" man wget
```

where

1. `+` symbol to execute next operation after `less` has opened
2. `/` command to start search
3. `^\s+-b` regexp to match `-b` from start of line

So if you like you can arrange the apropriate function for shell

```
function rman {
#USAGE: rman programm.name option.to.search (with "-" symbol)
LESS="+/^\s+$2" man "$1"
}
```

and add it into `~/.bashrc` for example.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I think because it will not do multiline matching

Answer (score 18):

When you run `man command` you can press `/` and then enter the plain text to search for. For example, type `/-b` and it'll jump to the first instance of `-b` in the text.

Comment: @drewbenn Oh, nice. I've always just pressed `/`+enter to continue on.

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a small script to do this called [he](https://github.com/mikelward/scripts/blob/master/he), e.g. `he wget -b`.

The basic strategy is: search for the option (e.g. `-b`) as the first word on a line, then print until the next header, or next line with matching indentation.

If you can't use that, you can get something similar using basic `sed`, e.g.

```
man wget | sed -ne '/^  *-b/,/^$/p'
```

Comment: Also your [desc](https://github.com/mikelward/scripts/blob/master/desc) script is very helpful.

Comment: Just decided to rename it to `he`, as in `short help`, plus `he`/`man`.

Comment: Updated to work with the new example, `wget -b`.

Comment: I cannot imagine why such simple functionality wasn't implemented natively and one should write a script to achieve that

Answer (score 3):

I use the following script that connects to [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/). I copied it from reddit some time ago:

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=$1
shift
args=$*
args=${args/ /+}
w3m -dump "https://explainshell.com/explain/$cmd?args=$args"| tail -n +10
```

I named it `rman` and put it in my `$PATH`. Usage for `wget -b`:

```
$ rman wget -b    
wget(1) -b

The non-interactive network downloader

-b
--background
    Go to background immediately after startup.  If no output file is specified via the -o, output is
    redirected to wget-log.

source manpages: wget
```

I got it from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/1lchjm/interactive_manpages/cbyjsnf). Thanks to the author!

Comment: It's important to note that this potentially documents a different implementation/version of the commands from those installed on the machine.

Comment: Also, there's no escaping and bad quoting in the code.

Comment: Yes, I wondered if I should emphasize that. However, if a particular option means something in one flavor of the program it ***usually*** means the same in another flavor. What is more often is that some options are missing. Again, this is just my experience.

Comment: @l0b0: I didn't write this code, I wouldn't use bash in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if your `grep` is the GNU `grep`,  you can use it as follows:

```
man wget | grep -EA3 '^ *-b'
```

In which `-A` (a GNU extension) is for print number of lines after matching lines (here `3`). you can use appropriate number for complete description.

Example:

```
$ man wget | grep -EA3 '^ *-b'
       -b
       --background
           Go to background immediately after startup.  If no output file is specified via the -o, output is
           redirected to wget-log.

$ man grep | grep -EA3 '^ *-A'
       -A NUM, --after-context=NUM
              Print NUM lines of trailing context after matching lines.  Places a line containing a  group  separator
              (--)  between  contiguous groups of matches.  With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect
              and a warning is given.
```

Answer (score 0):

For a command line experience, use @Costas version.

For a light weight version, `man` uses the same text interface as `less`. This means you can use the same commands as `less`.

```
# open manual to wget
man wget

# search for -b
/-b

# use "n" to navigate to next version of -b until you find what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `col -b` or `col -bx` before using `sed`:

```
$ man wget | col -bx | sed -n "/^  *-b/,/^$/p"
       -b
       --background
           Go to background immediately after startup.  If no output file is
           specified via the -o, output is redirected to wget-log.
```